# Preserve the formatting(whitespace & newlines) of the response received from executing a command over ssh

Tags: python, pexpect, repr, pxssh

I am writing an application in `Python`, I am using `pexpect` ( more specifically the `pxssh` functionality) to execute a series of commands on a Cisco Router. I want to store the output returned to a variable intact with the `whitespaces` and the `newlines`.

```
s = pxssh.pxssh(options={
        "StrictHostKeyChecking": "no",
        "UserKnownHostsFile": "/dev/null"})
```

After login and execute relevant command, I store the result in a dictionary:

`data[command]=repr(s.before)`

`repr` returns `/n` and the `/r` perfectly, however `whitespaces` are missing.

As an example the print(`s.before`) returns as below.

[image: Snapshot of the print(s.before)]

However with `repr` the best I am able to get (and consequently format) is as below:

[image: snapshot when using repr]

In where `whitespaces` and formatting are lost.

P.S. : I cannot write and read to the files. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you use to get this output? print? repr?

Comment: The first image is simply a print(s.before) - which is the format I want and the second image is when I store the s.before in a variable like : mytext= repr(s.before) and then replace the /n and /r with <br> { These are being printed in a html div}

Comment: The newline characters are preserved with repr but not the whitespaces, I want them spaces!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy/paste (or transcribe) the text directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're trying to save python string (with \n and whitespaces) and inject it in some html.

If you're having trouble with html view, wrap your string into `<pre>` tag to preserve formatting (including spaces). This is not issue with python (again, as far as I understand), you can check this by printing your variable or counting whitespaces inside python

Comment: Nope. I am unable to get the right spacing from the terminal output itself. I have tried repr and even redirecting the standard stdout. I get the new lines but not the spaces.

Comment: A combination of redirecting the standard stdout and <pre> worked. Thank you for the tip.